# How to calculate required cash flow for XIRR to get target return rate

Tags: vba, irr

I have the following dates and numbers: 1/1/2015, 6/1/2015, 12/1/2015, and 3/1/2016 with respective numbers -$1M, $100K, $100K, and X. I'm using the XIRR function. How do I solve for X so that I can get an XIRR for whichever target rate (let's say 5.50%)? I used the goal seek function but I would get a number for X that puts me close to 5.50% but always a little over (like 5.521%).

Is there a good way for me to approximate X in vba?

Answer (score 0):

```
With Application
        .MaxIterations = 10000
        .MaxChange = 0.0000001
Sheet3.Range("IRR").GoalSeek Goal:= 5.5%, ChangingCell:= B1
End With
```

I was able to solve it by using goalseek and changing the iterations and precision level.